# Powershell - Set-Content adding characters to line instead of overriding

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to override my contents within a json file but the contents keep adding to the line and not overriding. What did I do incorrectly?

```
$ActualContent = '"line1": "0 21 * * *'
$ContentToReplace = '"line1": "0 23 * * *'


Content = Get-Content $BaseFolder\$FileName -Raw 

# Change Content
$Content -replace $ActualContent,$ContentToReplace | Set-Content $BaseFolder\$FileName

Write-Host " The content $ActualContent has been replaced with $ContentToReplace" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Before code : `"line1": "0 21 * * *"`
After code : `line1": "0 23 * * ** * *"`

I did notice that if I add the " to the end then the script doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is easy to reproduce:

```
$content = '"line1": "0 21 * * *"'
$ActualContent = '"line1": "0 21 * * *'
$ContentToReplace = '"line1": "0 23 * * *'
$content -replace $ActualContent, $ContentToReplace # => "line1": "0 23 * * ** * *"
```

This is because the replacement operator [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) uses [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#character-ranges) to find patterns and replace them. `*` is a [special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#quantifiers), if you were looking to match a literal `*` you would need to [escape it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#escaping-characters) using `\`.

- `$contentToReplace` would become:

```
$ContentToReplace = '"line1": "0 23 \* \* \*'
```

Use https://regex101.com/r/hJZeos/1 to understand better what's going on.

Your issue should be easily fixed using the [`.Replace(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) string method which will match strings literally:

```
$content = '"line1": "0 21 * * *"'
$ActualContent = '"line1": "0 21 * * *'
$ContentToReplace = '"line1": "0 23 * * *'
$content.Replace($ActualContent, $ContentToReplace) # => "line1": "0 23 * * *"
```